# how to group dates from ms access database as week of month using excel vba

Tags: vba, excel, ms-access-2010

I am using MS access 2010 database and working with Excel VBA to connect to the database and make queries. Suppose I have a table named "MyTable" like this below:

```
----------------------
| Date   | Count    |
----------------------
|7/7/16  | 12       |
----------------------
|7/8/16  | 15       |
----------------------
|7/15/16 | 18       |
----------------------
|7/18/16 | 16       |
----------------------
|8/7/16  | 15       |
----------------------
|8/8/16  | 10       |
----------------------
|8/15/16 |  9       |
----------------------
|8/16/16 | 18       |
----------------------
```

Now I want to use query to get a table like this:

```
----------------------
|Week by Month | Sum |
----------------------
|July Week 2   | 27  |
----------------------
|July Week 3   | 18  |
----------------------
|July Week 4   | 16  |
----------------------
|Aug Week 2    | 25  |
----------------------
|Aug Week 3    | 27  |
----------------------
```

Comment: A variation on this answer might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/762242/access-query-sql-to-return-records-sorted-grouped-by-weeks.  Pretty sure you can adapt it to return week of the month instead of week of the year.

Comment: I have seen this post, but it gives the week number for the whole year, I need to calculate again from it to get which week of month and for that I can not use simple logic like 4 weeks/month because it depends on lot of factors depending on the year. So I posted this one. Can you highlight on this?

Comment: Can you add more details to your post about how you're supposed to handle weeks that are partially in one month and partially in another? In other words, where are your 'Week 1's in the table and can you ever have Week 5's? In your example, all the data is in the middle of the month.

Comment: 31st July, 2016 will be July week 5 whereas 1st Aug, 2016 will Aug week 1 though both of them falls in same week.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this as below:

```
select weeknum, sum(count1) from (
select  format(date1,'MMM') & " Week - " &  int((datepart('d',date1,1,1) -1 ) / 7 + 1) as weeknum, count1 from MyTable)
group by weeknum
```

Comment: You realize this doesn't take into account what days the weeks start on, right?  For example in July of 2016 your weeks start on a Friday and in June of 2016 they start on a Wednesday.

Answer (score 0):

Use DatePart to get the week of the *year*, then subtract the week of the first day of the month (zero based week of the month) and then add 1 (to get to a one based week of the month:

```
Public Function WeekOfMonth(x As Date) As Integer
    WeekOfMonth = DatePart("ww", x) - _
                  DatePart("ww", DateSerial(Year(x), Month(x), 1)) _
                  + 1
End Function
```

Note that the Access SQL version should be idential to what's after the `=` sign.

Comment: I need to use query.

Comment: @MeghdutSaha - "Note that the Access SQL version should be idential to what's after the = sign."

Answer (score -1):

Show Week of Month where Week 1 is always the 1st Full Week of the Month starting in that month (First Sunday is 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5 or 6 or 7), days of the month prior to the first Sunday are counted as week 4/5 of previous month.

After searching and failing to find EXACTLY the right answer for my situation - I modified ComIntern's solution as follows. This is used a CONTROL on a REPORT, where [StartDate] is a criteria on the form that calls/generates the report:

```
=IIf((DatePart("ww",[StartDate]-7)-DatePart("ww",DateSerial(Year([StartDate]-7),Month([StartDate]-7),1))+1)="5","1",DatePart("ww",[StartDate])-DatePart("ww",DateSerial(Year([StartDate]),Month([StartDate]),1))+0)
```

This results in showing the Week of Month based on FULL weeks - and accounts for when the previous month's week 5 included 1 or more days from this month.

For example - Week 5 of Oct 2017 is 29 OCT - 04 NOV.  If I did not include the IIF statement to adjust the formula, 05-11 NOV is returned as Week 2, but for my reporting purposes it is Week 1 of NOV.  I have tested this out and appears to ALWAYS work, if you need to see Week of Month, based on FULL weeks, this should work for you!